# sensor reading using crc 32 bit

Tags: crc32

I am trying to commucate with a sensor usimg 32 bit crc. I am using pre-built 32bit crc table. How can I implement error detection code? Sensor sends 38bytes of data with a header 0x93.
hank you for your answer here is the code part of my project.

```
for aye=bytePullIdx:(crcIdx-1) 
a = bitand(bitxor(byteBufferPtr(aye),bitshift(crc,-24)),hex2dec('FF'));
crc = bitxor(bitshift(crc,8),crcLookupTable2(a));
```

Above byteBufferPtr is coming message (38bytes) crcLookupTable is pre-built table for crc polynom '04C11DB7'. after calculating crc I check if (crc==byteBufferPtr(crcIdx) condition to get the data.
Is there anything wrong here? because I could not get the right if condition here. I could not find the right crc value among the crc table values.
Thank you.